# Mongodb aborting after fassert() failure

Tags: ubuntu, database, mongodb

I tried to reboot my server with `shutdown -rF now` command. After that I noticed mongodb service is not running. I tried to run it with `sudo service mongod start`, but the status is :

```
mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-02-09 14:18:29 +0330; 2s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2123 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
 Main PID: 2123 (code=exited, status=14)

Feb 09 14:18:28 example.com systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Feb 09 14:18:29 example.com mongod[2123]: 2018-02-09T14:18:29.013+0330 W CONTROL  [main] No SSL certificate validation can be 
Feb 09 14:18:29 example.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Feb 09 14:18:29 example.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 09 14:18:29 example.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

After that I tried to repair it with  `sudo mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`

then I faced this logs :

```
2018-02-09T14:24:08.348+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2236 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=example.com
2018-02-09T14:24:08.348+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.18
2018-02-09T14:24:08.348+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 4c1bae566c0c00f996a2feb16febf84936ecaf6f
2018-02-09T14:24:08.348+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-02-09T14:24:08.348+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-02-09T14:24:08.348+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-02-09T14:24:08.348+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-02-09T14:24:08.348+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-02-09T14:24:08.348+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-02-09T14:24:08.348+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-02-09T14:24:08.348+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { repair: true, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb" } }
2018-02-09T14:24:08.380+0330 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-02-09T14:24:08.380+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected WT journal files.  Running recovery from last checkpoint.
2018-02-09T14:24:08.380+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] journal to nojournal transition config: create,cache_size=6G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-02-09T14:24:08.400+0330 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (0) [1518173648:400739][2236:0x7f4d446fcc80], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: WiredTiger.turtle: encountered an illegal file format or internal value
2018-02-09T14:24:08.400+0330 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (-31804) [1518173648:400812][2236:0x7f4d446fcc80], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2018-02-09T14:24:08.400+0330 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28558
2018-02-09T14:24:08.400+0330 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


2018-02-09T14:24:08.428+0330 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x1559492 0x1558439 0x1558ca2 0x7f4d43301390 0x7f4d42f5b428 0x7f4d42f5d02a 0x14d5563 0x1275b5a 0x97de59 0x97e03f 0x97e205 0x1c3988c 0x1c381da 0x1bef994 0x1c75add 0x1c76009 0x1c762ac 0x1bfdae1 0x1c72978 0x1c379af 0x1c37a6c 0x1bec12c 0x125a57a 0x1253065 0x114e28e 0x9cb181 0x97efda 0x7f4d42f46830 0x9c6479
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"1159492","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"400000","o":"1158439"},{"b":"400000","o":"1158CA2"},{"b":"7F4D432F0000","o":"11390"},{"b":"7F4D42F26000","o":"35428","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7F4D42F26000","o":"3702A","s":"abort"},{"b":"400000","o":"10D5563","s":"_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi"},{"b":"400000","o":"E75B5A"},{"b":"400000","o":"57DE59","s":"__wt_eventv"},{"b":"400000","o":"57E03F","s":"__wt_err"},{"b":"400000","o":"57E205","s":"__wt_panic"},{"b":"400000","o":"183988C","s":"__wt_turtle_read"},{"b":"400000","o":"18381DA","s":"__wt_metadata_search"},{"b":"400000","o":"17EF994","s":"__wt_conn_btree_open"},{"b":"400000","o":"1875ADD","s":"__wt_session_get_btree"},{"b":"400000","o":"1876009","s":"__wt_session_get_btree"},{"b":"400000","o":"18762AC","s":"__wt_session_get_btree_ckpt"},{"b":"400000","o":"17FDAE1","s":"__wt_curfile_open"},{"b":"400000","o":"1872978"},{"b":"400000","o":"18379AF","s":"__wt_metadata_cursor_open"},{"b":"400000","o":"1837A6C","s":"__wt_metadata_cursor"},{"b":"400000","o":"17EC12C","s":"wiredtiger_open"},{"b":"400000","o":"E5A57A","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_S8_mbbb"},{"b":"400000","o":"E53065"},{"b":"400000","o":"D4E28E","s":"_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv"},{"b":"400000","o":"5CB181"},{"b":"400000","o":"57EFDA","s":"main"},{"b":"7F4D42F26000","o":"20830","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"400000","o":"5C6479","s":"_start"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.2.18", "gitVersion" : "4c1bae566c0c00f996a2feb16febf84936ecaf6f", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.4.0-104-generic", "version" : "#127-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 12:16:42 UTC 2017", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "3C61A0DBFA07F1A1069E23BC3A1ADF2E695605CE" }, { "b" : "7FFCD70B7000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BF4B5E36B7E2464DCF29A888C247A27A3FF2BC5C" }, { "b" : "7F4D4427C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DCF10134B91ED2139E3E8C72564668F5CDBA8522" }, { "b" : "7F4D43E38000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1649272BE0CA9FA22F082DC86372B6C9959779B0" }, { "b" : "7F4D43C30000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F951C1E0765FCAE48F82CAFE35D1ADD36D6C9AF9" }, { "b" : "7F4D43A2C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "0FC788F0861846257B5F1773FBD438E95DFC1032" }, { "b" : "7F4D43723000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FF7A33D389E756CA381A8189291A968EA5E1F4F8" }, { "b" : "7F4D4350D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7F4D432F0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "27F189EF8DB8C3734C6A678E6EF3CB0B206D58B2" }, { "b" : "7F4D42F26000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "088A6E00A1814622219F346B41E775B8DD46C518" }, { "b" : "7F4D444E5000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9157F205547F0EB588E2AB1F2F120B74253A43EA" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x1559492]
 mongod(+0x1158439) [0x1558439]
 mongod(+0x1158CA2) [0x1558ca2]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7f4d43301390]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x7f4d42f5b428]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x16A) [0x7f4d42f5d02a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0x93) [0x14d5563]
 mongod(+0xE75B5A) [0x1275b5a]
 mongod(__wt_eventv+0x3BA) [0x97de59]
 mongod(__wt_err+0x8B) [0x97e03f]
 mongod(__wt_panic+0x24) [0x97e205]
 mongod(__wt_turtle_read+0x24C) [0x1c3988c]
 mongod(__wt_metadata_search+0x8A) [0x1c381da]
 mongod(__wt_conn_btree_open+0x64) [0x1bef994]
 mongod(__wt_session_get_btree+0xDD) [0x1c75add]
 mongod(__wt_session_get_btree+0x609) [0x1c76009]
 mongod(__wt_session_get_btree_ckpt+0x12C) [0x1c762ac]
 mongod(__wt_curfile_open+0x151) [0x1bfdae1]
 mongod(+0x1872978) [0x1c72978]
 mongod(__wt_metadata_cursor_open+0x5F) [0x1c379af]
 mongod(__wt_metadata_cursor+0x3C) [0x1c37a6c]
 mongod(wiredtiger_open+0x18DC) [0x1bec12c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_S8_mbbb+0x86A) [0x125a57a]
 mongod(+0xE53065) [0x1253065]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x3EE) [0x114e28e]
 mongod(+0x5CB181) [0x9cb181]
 mongod(main+0x73A) [0x97efda]
 libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF0) [0x7f4d42f46830]
 mongod(_start+0x29) [0x9c6479]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
Aborted
```